# Access Organization repo on Github using Personal Access Token inside Bash script

Tags: bash, git, github

I'm trying to clone a repo using the following syntax inside a bash script

```
git clone "https://oauth2:[TOKEN]@github.com/[organization]/$reponame.git $REPOPATH/$reponame"
```

and I get the following error:

```
Cloning into 'protos-cusum_hmm-python'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/[organization]/protos-cusum_hmm-python.git /opt/protolangs/protos-cusum_hmm-python/': The requested URL returned error: 400
```

when I clone directly from command line `git clone https://github.com/[organizaiton]/protos-cusum_hmm-python.git` it works fine (presumable because it's using my cached credentials)

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Removed quotations around url (`git clone https://oauth2:[TOKEN]@github.com/[organization]/$reponame.git $REPOPATH/$reponame`) and now getting

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/fluxusinc/protos-cusum_hmm-python.git/'
```

EDIT2:

When hardcoded with token:

```
git clone "https://ghp_...O17xckH@github.com/[organization]/"$reponame".git" $REPOPATH/$reponame
```

it works, so seems like it's a problem with the `YAML`

```
- name: Run proto builder and deploy to repos
        env:
          P_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.REPO_TOKEN }}
        run: |
           chmod +x "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/build.sh"
           "$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/build.sh"
        shell: bash
```

Comment: what about using your username instead of `oauth2` or removing `oauth2:` at all?

Comment: @dan1st `git clone https://$TOKEN@github.com/[organization]/$reponame.git $REPOPATH/$reponame` yields `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address`

Comment: and what about supplying the actual username?

Comment: `remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/[organization]/protos-cusum_hmm-python.git/'`

Comment: @dan1st it seems like it's a problem with the variable getting passed properly to the bash script, because when I hardcode it in, it can clone.... here's the the relevant YAML (see above)

Comment: Are you writing, literally, `[TOKEN]`? That is, left square bracket, uppercase T, uppercase O, ..., uppercase N, right square bracket? If so, that's a problem, because bash won't do any variable substitution with square brackets. Use `https://$TOKEN@github.com/path/to/repo.git` (with literal dollar sign, uppercase T, etc) and at most double quotes around that, so that bash *will* expand `$TOKEN`.

Comment: @torek exact input (with [organization] replaced by actual org name):

`git clone https://$P_TOKEN@github.com/[organization]/$reponame.git $REPOPATH/$reponame`

actual output:
`fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address`

Comment: Hm, but your `env:` line says `TOKEN`, not `P_TOKEN`. So `$P_TOKEN` would be empty (accessing an unset variable by default produces the empty string; you have to set a bash option to get an error when you use an unset variable). The `@` should give something heartburn at that point, I would think, but perhaps Git just says "oh I guess I need to ask for a user name on the keyboard now" and tries to do that (which obviously fails, `No such device or address` because `/dev/tty` isn't hooked up).

Comment: Been messing around with this all day, indeed my `env` has `P_TOKEN` now, updated above accordingly

Comment: OK, if they match up, I would think this should Just Work. Do GitHub save the output from running the bash script? If so I'd set the debug options (`set -x` is the main one here) and watch what actually gets run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239298/discussion-between-joshp-and-torek).

Answer (score 1):

much thanks to @torek....

turns out for whatever reason I had to put the secret in the repo rather than the organization and it worked... not sure why that was the case because github is showing it overriding

[image: github secret]

MORE INFO:

was able to figure out by setting the secret `ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG` to `true` from [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging).

yielded

```
##[debug]Evaluating: secrets.REPO_TOKEN_GRPC
##[debug]Evaluating Index:
##[debug]..Evaluating secrets:
##[debug]..=> Object
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'REPO_TOKEN_GRPC'
##[debug]=> null
##[debug]Result: null
```

showing that the token was empty for whatever reason